# insering a mongoose record if not found

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The mongoose schema looks like:

```
var followSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {type: String, required: true},
  following : []
});
```

The Objective is to look for a user using the ID field and then add items to the following array.

The below method does not work:

```
var myRecord = FollowModel.findOneAndUpdate({userId: req.user.Id}, {upsert: true});
    myRecord.exec(function(err, result) {

        result.following.push('Test');
        res.status(200).send('New Item Added to Follow List');

    });
```

How is this to be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, you just forgot to include the `{ "new": true }` option, as well as a valid update statment:

```js
FollowModel.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "userId": req.user.Id}, 
   { "$setOnInsert": {

   }},
   { "upsert": true, "new": true },
   function(err,result) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(result);
   }
```

);

The blank [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) here will no nothing in this case, but otherwise you would put something in there that you wanted created "on insert". This would be applied along with any fields in the "query" portion of the statement.

Other standard [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) can also apply, but generally in the case where something "is" matched that you want to update.

But it's the `{ "new": true }` here that lets the command know to return the "modified or created" document, rather than the "original or non existing" document, which is the default without that option.